# Cron job not working (CURL)

Tags: cron

I have a server using Linux 19.04

First I did: `nano /etc/crontab`

The below things were already in the file

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
13 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
18 00   * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
33 00   * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
43 00   1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

I added this one at the end before `#` line

`*/1 * * * * curl -s "https://www.example.com/abc" > /dev/null`

Comment: did you do that command manually, once, to be sure it work?  try it without `-s` and with output redirected to a file so you can look at it carefully.

Comment: Also, `*/1` is the same as `*`.

Comment: It's doubful that you have a user named 'curl'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this file is made for that purpose, I normally use standart cronfunctionality to run jobs regularly, but maybe it is possible.
But, as you can see there is a user-field in this file, so you should also fill it, and after that, to be sure, yoy sould retart cron:

> sudo systemctl restart cron.service

Comment: You don't need to restart `cron` to get your modified crontab working.

Comment: I just want to open example.com/abc page every 1 minute in the background